# Type from an exclusion (?) of values

Tags: typescript

I know that I can define a type as a union of values:

```js
type Names = 'Alex' | 'Jason' | 'Tony';
```

But I'm optimistically thinking I might be able to define types as everything *but* a value:

```js
type NotAlex = string | !'Alex'
```

This may be wishful thinking, ultimately what I'd like to do is be able to say something like:

```js
interface IThingWithTime {
    time: number;
    [key: string]: [number, number];
}
```

Without the compiler telling me:

> Property 'time' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index
>   type '[number, number]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently. There was a proposal to include [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) and [custom index signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797), but they did not make it into the language (and negated types currently [seem dead](https://youtu.be/obvOZn639ms?t=2078))

You can get around the error you are referencing using intersection types:

```
type IThingWithTime = {
    time: number;
} & {
    [key: string]: [number, number];
}
```

Although you may run into inconsistencies because the type is inconsistent.

Comment: Many thanks! It's interesting to hear that negated types are dead... I can't watch the video that you linked just yet, but given the amount of feedback on the pull request, it's a shame that this hasn't proceeded

Comment: @OliverRadini The link is from a Q&A at TS conf. I specifically asked about negated types as I was also looking forward to them. Ryan and Anders explain why they are at least holding back on them for now, you should give it a listen (I linked to the exact time so it's just a 5 min listen, although the rest was also interesting :) )

Comment: I'll certainly take a look when I can; sounds like an interesting topic and I'll be keeping a look out to see if there's any more news

Comment: I watched the segment you referenced; they make very interesting points and it does seem like negated types will stay out of the language... and maybe for the best!